# Limiting data while traveling

Tags: gmail

I am traveling in Europe and want to limit the amount of data I use when I open an email.  Is there some way to turn off images or data intensive graphics?

Comment: Can you describe how you're accessing your mail? Are you using gmail's web portal directly?

Comment: Under General Settings, there's a setting for External Content. (You can force Gmail to prompt you before downloading any external content, including images.) Was there something more than that you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Using http://m.gmail.com gives you a simple but functional interface, that as far as I can see displays emails in text mode without any images.